# Jenkins Java API and build parameters

Tags: java, api, jenkins

I am integrating an external tool with Jenkins. Part of the integration requires that user must be able to invoke parametrized builds using Jenkins remoting Java API /as described here: 
[Kohsuke Kawaguchi's example git repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cli-channel-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/demo/cli/App.java)/;

The parameters will vary depending on what is being build, i.e. for maven they will be artefact & group ids, for freestyle projects - folder paths, file names etc.

Is there a plugin/setting which allows you to do that?

I though of creating a Jenkins pre-build step which parses and transforms whatever parameters we send through /relying on some naming convention/ and then invokes the main Jenkins build step.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean here. You're talking about *user* triggering build using *Java API*, which doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: ok, I am sorry -  user triggers action in our tool, cherry-picks parameters and then tool uses the values to schedule remote build through jenkins java api

Comment: If you want to write a Jenkins plugin to integrate with your external tool, take a look at this link : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins.

Comment: @JohnStadt you probably want to use Jenkins CLI for that, as suggested in that answer. Java API is something you would use from Java code, in your own Jenkins plugin.

Comment: edited to clarify, see link in question for an example of how I need to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is create a single reusable Jenkins build job, passing in all the variables at run-time? Difficult to maintain that kind of setup, I'd argue it's simpler to use the Jenkins API to automatically generate a Jenkins job for each project.

For complex parameter handling, perhaps you should consider an alternative tool like [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/)? It is a tool that complements Jenkins (See [Rundeck plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin)) and is best suited to general automation tasks across a network of machines. I mention it in this context because it has a very flexible mechanism for configuring job options and you could use it to run your builds....

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) which allows you to access Jenkins from a script or from your shell.